# How to intercept call and serve back JSON file dynamically (without "import")

Tags: json, angular, mocking, angular8, angular-http-interceptors

I have a scaffolding of folders and json files to mock an API's paths. When I run `npm run start:mock`, `LocalMockInterceptor` gets provisioned and e.g. replaces a call to *host/A/B/C* by an http call getting locally *Folder A/Folder B/C.json*. The JSON files get produced by a separate script which is out of scope here. I cannot make use of "import" as many tutorials show because I need a generic solution as the API i am mocking will evolve over time (and so will this scaffolding of folders and files).

```
/**
 * The idea is to only build this into the bundle if we specify so (e.g. on TeamCity, on your localhost), where you don't want to rely
 * on external resources for development
 * No conditionals in the code bundle! No configuration files or database dependency.
 */
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ErrorService } from './error.service';

const devAssetsFolder = 'assets';

@Injectable()
export class LocalMockInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private errorService: ErrorService,
    private injector: Injector,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.url.endsWith('.json')) return next.handle(request);
    console.log(
      ` >>> Mock Interceptor >>> ${request.url} has been intercepted`
    );
    const path = `${devAssetsFolder}${request.url}.json`;
    var promise = this.getJSON(path).toPromise();
    const jsonheaders = new HttpHeaders();
    jsonheaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let json2;
    promise
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
        json2 = json;
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    Promise.all([promise]);
    console.log(json2);
    return of(
      new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: json2, headers: jsonheaders })
    );
  }

  private getJSON(jsonPath: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(jsonPath);
  }
}
```

- The first conditional is to avoid infinite loops since I am sending HTTP requests in my interceptor
- Getting the path to the JSON file based on the URL is quite natural
- It seemed to me that I have to convert the JSON Observable into a promise so that I can wait for it to complete before rewrapping that json into the returned Observable. When debugging however, it seems `Promise.all` is not waiting for the promise to complete (`json2` is undefined on the next line), and I end up sending an empty http body back...

  1. How to fix this rxjs promise ?
  2. Is inner HTTP calls my only option ?
  3. Is there a way not to rely on promises ? Can you think of a better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try just modifying the target URL in your interceptor ? You want to make an API call that return some JSON but instead of calling a dynamic API, you just want to call you static server so it can return predefined JSON.

```
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const fakeUrl = `${devAssetsFolder}${request.url}.json`;
    const fakeRequest = request.clone({url: fakeUrl});
    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.url.endsWith('.json')) return next.handle(request);
    console.log(
      ` >>> Mock Interceptor >>> ${request.url} has been intercepted`
    );
    const path = `${devAssetsFolder}${request.url}.json`;
    return this.getJSON(path).pipe(map(result => {
      const jsonheaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      return 
        new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: result, headers: jsonheaders });
    }), // you can also add catchError here
    );
  }
```

In intercept method you can return an observable. So your `getJSON` method returns an observable, we added pipe a map function which maps the result to new http response. If your response already has the right headers you don't even need the pipe and map functions you can just do this :

```
 return this.getJSON(path); // it's an observable, so it's OK.
```

Comment: I was not able to get this one to compile after a few changes. Went with the solution from Noemi, but would be interested to see this solution working as well for my understanding.